# Estou tentando fazer um cadastro em C, mas o código não deixa colocar o endereço

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um cadastro em C, mas o código não deixa colocar o endereço e quando coloco a opção pra finalizar o cadastro o programa trava e para de funcionar. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char endereco, nome, cpf;
    int rg, cnh, codigo, opcao, dn;

    printf("Nome do Cliente: ");
    scanf("%s",&nome);

    printf("\nEndereco do Cliente: ");
    scanf("%s",&endereco);

    printf("\nNumero da Identidade (somente numeros):");
    scanf("%s",&rg);

    printf("\nNumero do CPF: ");
    scanf("%s",&cpf);

    printf("\nNumero da CNH (somente numeros): ");
    scanf("%s",&cnh);

    printf("\nCódigo do Cliente (somente numeros): ");
    scanf("%s",&codigo);

    printf("\nData de Nascimento (somente numeros): ");
    scanf("%s",&dn);

    printf("\nFinalizar Cadastro");
    printf("\n1 - Salvar");
    printf("\n2 - Cancelar\n");
    scanf("%s", opcao);
    if(opcao=1)
    {
        printf("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");
    }
    else(opcao=2);
    {
        printf("Cadastro cancelado.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, `=` é operador de atribuição, enquanto que `==` é de comparação. Assim sendo, você deveria usar `if (opcao == 1)` ao invés de `if(opcao=1)`.

No seu `else` está faltando um `if` depois e tem um `;` a mais. Como resultado, o `else(opcao=2);{` troca o valor de `opcao` para 2 e executa o que está dentro do `{` que se segue. Não é isso o que você quer. O que você queria é `else if (opcao == 2) {`.

Segundo, que você está confundindo caracteres com strings. Ao invés de `char endereco, nome, cpf;`, deveria usar `char endereco[50], nome[50], cpf[12];`. O motivo é que esses campos são representados cada um por uma sequência de caracteres (string), e não por um caractere isolado. O número que aparece é o tamanho máximo da string. Lembre-se que em C, todas as strings têm um terminador nulo que consome um caractere, e portanto é importante deixar espaço para ele.

Outro erro é isso:

```
scanf("%s", opcao);
```

O que você queria era isso:

```
scanf("%d", opcao);
```

Entretanto, ler qualquer coisa com o `scanf` é uma coisa bem torturosa de fazer. É muito fácil fazer essa função horrorosa dar pau.

Uma alternativa é usar [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) para ler a entrada, no entanto, é necessário retirar-se a quebra de linha do final (uma função específica é capaz de fazer isso). No entanto, isso significa que cada string deve ter dois caracteres a mais do que o seu limite: um para o terminador nulo e outro para a quebra-de-linha que o `fgets` acrescenta.

Use [`atoi`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) para converter string em número.

Eis o seu código corrigido:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void removerNL(char *c) {
    c[strlen(c) - 1] = 0;
}

int main() {
    printf("Nome do Cliente: ");
    char nome[50];
    fgets(nome, 50, stdin);
    removerNL(nome);

    printf("\nEndereco do Cliente: ");
    char endereco[50];
    fgets(endereco, 50, stdin);
    removerNL(endereco);

    printf("\nNumero da Identidade (somente numeros):");
    char rg[20];
    fgets(rg, 20, stdin);
    removerNL(rg);

    printf("\nNumero do CPF: ");
    char cpf[13];
    fgets(cpf, 13, stdin);
    removerNL(cpf);

    printf("\nNumero da CNH (somente numeros): ");
    char cnh[20];
    fgets(cnh, 20, stdin);
    removerNL(cnh);

    printf("\nCódigo do Cliente (somente numeros): ");
    char scodigo[5];
    fgets(scodigo, 5, stdin);
    removerNL(scodigo);
    int codigo = atoi(scodigo);

    printf("\nData de Nascimento (somente numeros): ");
    char data[10];
    fgets(data, 10, stdin);
    removerNL(data);

    printf("\nFinalizar Cadastro");
    printf("\n1 - Salvar");
    printf("\n2 - Cancelar\n");

    char sopcao[5];
    fgets(sopcao, 5, stdin);
    removerNL(sopcao);
    int opcao = atoi(sopcao);

    if (opcao == 1) {
        printf("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!\n");
    } else if (opcao == 2) {
        printf("Cadastro cancelado.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Opcao desconhecida %d.\n", opcao);
    }

    printf("Nome: %s\n", nome);
    printf("Endereco: %s\n", endereco);
    printf("RG: %s\n", rg);
    printf("CPF: %s\n", cpf);
    printf("CNH: %s\n", cnh);
    printf("Codigo: %d\n", codigo);
    printf("Nascimento: %s\n", data);
}
```

Observe que no código acima, eu coloquei um monte de `printf` no final para mostrar o que ele gravou. Se você rodar esse programa com essa entrada:

```
Nome do Cliente: Vanessa da Silva
Endereco do Cliente: Rua do C++, 27
Numero da Identidade (somente numeros): 34467885-7
Numero do CPF: 25022198258
Numero da CNH (somente numeros): 6879326283
Código do Cliente (somente numeros): 34
Data de Nascimento (somente numeros): 10081973
1
```

Eis a saída:

```
Finalizar Cadastro
1 - Salvar
2 - Cancelar
Cadastro realizado com sucesso!
Nome: Vanessa da Silva
Endereco: Rua do C++, 27
RG: 34467885-7
CPF: 25022198258
CNH: 6879326283
Codigo: 34
Nascimento: 10081973
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/t3xtgg)

Comment: Pra que serve esse:         void removerNL(char *c) {
    c[strlen(c) - 1] = 0;
}

Comment: @ClarissaGalvao Para retirar a quebra de linha que o `fgets` coloca no final da string lida.

Comment: Você é uma passoa incrivel! Valeu!

Comment: @ClarissaGalvao Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não te restar mais nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no "✅" aqui do lado, o que também marca a sua pergunta como respondida/solucionada. Se por outro lado, ainda não estiver satisfeita, deixe um comentário e vamos esclarecer.

Answer (score 1):

O if tem que ter 2 iguais, ou seja `if(opcao == 1)`. Trabalho só com PHP, mas acredito que em C também é assim, apenas um sinal de igual `=`, quer dizer que você está acrescentando algo aquilo, dois sinais de igual `==` está verificando se é igual.

Outra coisa é que tem um ponto e virgula no seu `else` acredito que também esteja errado.

Outra coisa errada é que o else não pode ter uma condição, ele é apenas else (se não). Você teria que usar o `else if`

```
if(opcao == 1){
    printf("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");
} else if(opcao == 2) {
    printf("Cadastro cancelado.");
}
```

[Linguagem C - Operadores](http://www.mspc.eng.br/info/cpp_oper_10.shtml)

Comment: Fiz as modificações e as opções não funcionam. O programa para de funcionar.

Comment: @ClarissaGalvao como eu disse, eu só trabalho com PHP, essa parte do if - else se você consertou, creio que agora está Ok. Outra parte do código eu não sei te informar se está certo ou não, porque eu não conheço muito bem a linguagem C.

Comment: Em C não existe `===`. Só existe `=` para atribuição e `==` para comparação.

Comment: Corrigido, Victor!

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode cadastrar um CPF como um inteiro, mesmo que seja sem pontos, já que isso retornaria um inteiro mto grande. Você até poderia usar um unsigned long int, mas caso seu sistema seja de 32 bits. Poderia acontecer um buffer overflow. Use a dica do amigo acima, pq esse é o melhor jeito de ser feito seu programa. E sempre se atente ao uso da memória em C.