# Código não faz a multiplicação. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazendo a multiplicação, mas simplesmente não aparece o resultado do calculo, o que está errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void removerNL(char *c) {
    c[strlen(c) - 1] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    int resultado;

    printf("\nCodigo do Locacao (somente numeros): ");
    char scodigoLoca[5];
    fgets(scodigoLoca, 5, stdin);
    removerNL(scodigoLoca);
    int codigoLoca = atoi(scodigoLoca);

    printf("\nCodigo do Cliente (somente numeros): ");
    char scodigoCliente[5];
    fgets(scodigoCliente, 5, stdin);
    removerNL(scodigoCliente);
    int codigoCliente = atoi(scodigoCliente);

    printf("\nValor do automovel: ");
    char svalor[10];
    fgets(svalor, 10, stdin);
    removerNL(svalor);
    int valor = atoi(svalor);

    printf("\nQuantidade de automoveis: ");
    char squant[5];
    fgets(squant, 5, stdin);
    removerNL(squant);
    int quant = atoi(squant);

    resultado = valor*quant;


    printf("Codigo de locacao: %d\n", codigoLoca);
    printf("Codigo do cliente: %d\n", codigoCliente);
    printf("Valor: %d\n", valor);
    printf("Quantidade: %d\n", quant);
    printf("\nValor total da locacao: ", resultado);

}
```

Comment: Relacionada (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250852/132

Comment: Você esqueceu o `%d` no seu último `printf`.

Comment: Veja funcionando: https://ideone.com/wvT9Zv; note que a remoção do NL vai retornar o valor errado caso se esqueça do enter (como foi neste caso de teste automatizado), recomendaria olhar se o caracter em `strlen(c) - 1` realmente é `\n`

Comment: Para remover os possiveis `\r` e/ou `\n` do final de um `buffer` preenchido pelo `fgets()`, basta: `buffer[ strcspn( buffer, "\r\n" ) ] = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de usar `fgets()` combinado com `atoi()`:

```
char svalor[10];
fgets(svalor, 10, stdin);
removerNL(svalor);
int valor = atoi(svalor);
```

Você pode simplesmente pode utilizar `scanf()`:

```
int valor;
scanf("%d", &valor);
```

Segue uma versão melhorada do seu código usando `scanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int resultado, codigoLoca, codigoCliente, valor, quant;

    printf("\nCodigo do Locacao (somente numeros): ");
    scanf("%d", &codigoLoca);

    printf("\nCodigo do Cliente (somente numeros): ");
    scanf("%d", &codigoCliente);

    printf("\nValor do automovel: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor);

    printf("\nQuantidade de automoveis: ");
    scanf("%d", &quant);

    resultado = valor * quant;

    printf("Codigo de locacao: %d\n", codigoLoca);
    printf("Codigo do cliente: %d\n", codigoCliente);
    printf("Valor: %d\n", valor);
    printf("Quantidade: %d\n", quant);
    printf("\nValor total da locacao: %d\n", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

Porém, se o intento é mesmo utilizar o par de funções `fgets()`/`atoi()`, sugiro a utilização de um *buffer* único. Repare que `atoi()` faz a conversão do *buffer* para um valor inteiro sem a necessidade de remover o `new line` do final.

Segue outra versão melhorada do seu código usando `fgets()` e `atoi()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUF   (10)

int main()
{
    int resultado, codigoLoca, codigoCliente, valor, quant;
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    printf("\nCodigo do Locacao (somente numeros): ");
    fgets(buf, MAX_BUF, stdin);
    codigoLoca = atoi(buf);

    printf("\nCodigo do Cliente (somente numeros): ");
    fgets(buf, MAX_BUF, stdin );
    codigoCliente = atoi(buf);

    printf("\nValor do automovel: ");
    fgets( buf, MAX_BUF, stdin );
    valor = atoi(buf);

    printf("\nQuantidade de automoveis: ");
    fgets( buf, MAX_BUF, stdin );
    quant = atoi(buf);

    resultado = valor * quant;

    printf("Codigo de locacao: %d\n", codigoLoca);
    printf("Codigo do cliente: %d\n", codigoCliente);
    printf("Valor: %d\n", valor);
    printf("Quantidade: %d\n", quant);
    printf("\nValor total da locacao: %d\n", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```